# How to get finally inserted sql table name?

Tags: sql-server-2012

In my TestDB database i have three tables like Table1, Table2 & Table3.

IF anyone insert any one of the table how to know which table was inserted. If there is any syntax for fetching the table name.

E.g:

If anyone newly inserted data in Table2. I need to know the table name. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this query you can get details about most recently updated table names.

```
SELECT name, [modify_date] FROM sys.tables order by modify_date DESC
```

hope this helps!